# How to Initialize ArcObjects license in a 64 bit process (such as ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcobjects, license, 64bit

Attempts to initialize an ArcObjects license fails in a 64 bit process.  The same code works fine in 32 bit process.

*Update: I'm able to bind to the server runtime in 64 bit console app on a machine where Server is installed (but where desktop is not authorized).  Next I will attempt to do this on a machine where Server is installed but not authorized.  (Desktop is installed and authorized.)*

While some are under the impression that ArcObjects won't work in 64 bit mode, I know this is not true.  I've written custom GP Tools using ArcObjects that run in 64 bit Background Geoprocessing. In a GPTool however, I don't have to deal with initializing a license. But now, I need to.

*How do I initialize an arcobjects license in a 64 bit process?*

Eventually the .NET class library assembly needs to be called from a module built with ArcGIS Pro SDK v1.4.  For now I'm just trying to use it from a simple console app. I'm assuming in both cases I'll need to initialize an arcobjects after calling `RuntimeManager.Bind`, which is in the ESRI.ArcGIS.Version assembly.

The library works in 32 bit mode, but I get a runtime exception when it tries to load the assembly in 64 bit mode:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' 
occurred in ESRI.ArcGIS.Version.dll

Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'ArcGISVersion.dll': 
The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I tried registering the dll:

```
%windir%\syswow64\regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS
\bin\ArcGISVersion.dll"
```

But get same error.  I've downloaded and installed the Background Geoprocessing package.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, Kirk, but why aren't you using the Pro ArcObjects?

Comment: I'm working on a project with legacy ArcObjects based assemblies. We'd like to get it working in Pro without completely re-writing it. (Many lines of code).

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\ArcGISVersion.dll is a 32bit dll, you cannot call it from 64bit code. There is no legacy 64bit ArcObjects that I've ever witnessed; yes, there's 64bit python background geoprocessing dlls' but that's not ArcObjects, not the full set of interfaces and classes.

Comment: This [kb article](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000011695) describes how to register a custom arcobjects-based GP tool, so that it runs within the background geoprocessor, which is 64 bit. Here's the code it references [in github](https://github.com/Esri/arcobjects-sdk-community-samples/tree/master/Net/Geoprocessing/GPCustomCalculateAreaFunctionTool) can run in 64 bit mode. Since Pro is 64 bit, I was thinking I should be able to run similar code within an extension there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed - but did not authorize - ArcGIS Server on my machine.

I was then able to set references in my Visual Studio ArcGIS Pro project to the Esri.ArcGIS assemblies, compile and use them in their full x64 glory.

Interestingly, I didn't need to initialize a license before using them in Pro, as was required in a standalone x64 exe.

Comment: Very interesting finding, thanks for sharing. Crazy setup you have. :)

Comment: FYI we are using this approach with the new/stripped down 64 bit ArcObjects aka "ArcGIS Enterprise SDK. https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/sdk/latest/windows/webframe.html . Thanks much